# c# dropdownlist selectedindexchanged in gridview sets selectedindex of second dropdownlist

Tags: c#, gridview, drop-down-menu, selectedindexchanged

I have a gridview with two dropdownlists populated from a db. One is a descriptive name, the other is an abbreviated name. I need to accomplish the following:

When I select an item in DDL1 I need to change the selected index of DDL2 to match, and vice versa.

I have searched on here and found the following:

```
protected void ddlAddLabTest_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DropDownList ddlLabTest = (DropDownList)sender;
   GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)ddlLabTest.NamingContainer;
   DropDownList ddlAddLabTestShortName = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlAddShortname");

   ddlAddLabTestShortName.SelectedIndex = intSelectedIndex;
}
```

Only when it gets to the assignment for "row" I receive the following:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridItem' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow'.
```

I have tried finding a working example but I can't. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried a javascript solution or do you need to postback? If the DDLs are always going to equal eachother, why do you need both?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
protected void ddlAddLabTest_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DropDownList ddlLabTest = (DropDownList)sender;
   DataGridItem row = (DataGridItem) ddlLabTest.NamingContainer;
   DropDownList ddlAddLabTestShortName = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlAddShortname");

   ddlAddLabTestShortName.SelectedIndex = intSelectedIndex;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I had to use _GridViewRow_ instead of _DataGridItem_ But it worked! :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the `NamingContainer` is not a row, so leave it like that. It already has the `FindControl` method.

```
var row = ddlLabTest.NamingContainer;
```

Comment: Tried that: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.UI.Controls' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: Remove the GridViewRow type. Use var.